# FIrebase login with react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, postman

I am trying to get Authorisation token with react with the help of firebase. I am using postman to get request. I successfully wrote the signup route and in working correctly but I am not sure why the login route is not working.

This is my code for login route

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const user = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    };

    let errors = {};
    if(isEmpty(user.email)) errors.email = 'Must not be empty'
    if(isEmpty(user.password)) errors.password = 'Must not be empty'


    if(Objects.keys(errors).length > 0) return res.status(400).json(errors);

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then(data => {
            return data.user.getIdToken();
        })
        .then(token => {
            return res.json({token});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            if (err.code === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                return res
                    .status(403).json({general: 'Wrong Credentials, please try again'})
            }
            return res.status(500).json({error: err.code})
        })
})
```

This is my code for signup route

```
app.post('/signup', ( req, res ) => {
    // Users credentails
    const newUser = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
        handle: req.body.handle,
    };
    let errors = {};                // this is used to check if there will be any errors

    // checks errors in email address
    if(isEmpty(newUser.email)) {
        errors.email = 'Must not be empty'
    }   else if (!isEmail(newUser.email)) {
        errors.email = 'Must be a valid email address'
    }

    // checks errors in password and confirmPassword
    if(isEmpty(newUser.password))   errors.password = 'Must not be empty'
    if(newUser.password !== newUser.confirmPassword)    errors.confirmPassword = 'Passwords do not match'
    if(isEmpty(newUser.handle))   errors.handle = 'Must not be empty'

    // Return 400 error if there are any errors present
    if(Object.keys(errors).length > 0) return res.status(400).json(errors)

    // TODO validate data
    let token, userId;
    db.doc(`users/${newUser.handle}`).get()
        .then( doc => {
            if(doc.exists) {
                return res.status(400).json( { handle: 'this handle is already taken' } )
            } else {
                return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            userId = data.user.uid;
            return data.user.getIdToken()
        })
        .then(idtoken => {
            token = idtoken;
            const userCredentials = {
                handle: newUser.handle,
                email: newUser.email,
                createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
                userId
            };
            return db.doc(`users/${newUser.handle}`).set(userCredentials);
        })
        .then(() => {
            return res.status(201).json( { token })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            if(err.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use'){
                return res.status(400).json( { email: 'Email is already in use'})
            } else {
                return res.status(500).json( { error: err.code })
            }
        });
});
```

I have checked the authorization of email on firebase. I am getting

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Internal Server Error</pre>
</body>

</html>
``` of error code 500(internal server error) on postman.
````

Comment: what's the output of `console.error(err);` in login route? and also add the screenshot of postman with request params and result

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate from server side? `signInWithEmailAndPassword` supposed to be used in front end.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the same course and ran into same issue. I found that I only had the issue if when I saved and used `$ firebase serve`

When I tried it through `$ firebase deploy`, I had no issues.